# uploading image on Soundcloud's playlist

Tags: image, soundcloud, playlist, uploading

I uploaded an hi-res image on a Soundcloud's playlist but the result is very low. Here's The page: http://www.stefanolentini.net/listen/
The pic is 1990x1600. Does Soundcloud compress pictures? Any tips to have hi-res image?

Thank you in advance for your collaboration!

S

Comment: Re-upload with your most powerful device, your best Wi-Fi, and a lot of battery. After seeing the image there, wait a few seconds before saving.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended size for uploading images to Soundcloud is at least 800 x 800, so it's a square. The image on soundcloud is absolutely fine because it's square shape. If you resize your brower you will find that when you resize the player to a square the image is great. What you have is a stretched image no a compressed image.

I would put the player inside a div that keeps it square.